# Проблема с голосовым ассистентом хелп плиз

Tags: python

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeBvw.jpg -- ошибка

````
`r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone(device_index = 1)

with m as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

speak_engine = pyttsx3.init()


#Если установлены голоса
voices = speak_engine.getProperty('voices')
speak_engine.SetProperty('voice', voices[4].id)
speak_engine.SetProperty('volume', 1)

speak("Добрый день, мой создатель")
speak("Айро слушает..")
speak("Создатель, воспроизводи свою речь грамотно и понятно. Я могу не понять, или обидеться) Ха")

stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)
while True: time.sleep(0.1)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Может быть не SetProperty, а setProperty